# Number theory proof with inequality on primes

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Prove that for $n \geq 5$, $p^3_{n+1} \leq p_1\cdot p_2 \cdot ....\cdot p_n$ where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime.

I don't understand where to begin. My first thought was to prove $p^3_{n+1} \leq p_{n-2} \cdot p_{n-1} \cdot p_{n}$ as this utilises $3$ numbers and i have a cube on $LHS$. However i have no idea as to how i would go about proving this claim or if it is even true.

Kindly provide some hints or solutions. I sincerely ask you to limit yourself to the most basic stuff while proving this as the question comes from an exercise before which we haven't learned a lot. Thanks a lot.

Comment: $p_{n+1}$ is greater than $p_{n-2}, p_{n-1}$ and $p_n$ so one should not expect the product of those three to exceed $p_{n+1}^3$.

Comment: This follows from [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate) plus some algebra (and some  small cases).  Perhaps there is a more elementary solution, however.

Answer (score 1):

As @lulu said, Bertrand's postulate helps us to understand that
$$p_{n+1}<2p_n<4p_{n-1}<8p_{n-2}.$$
So for $n\geq 7$ we have
$$p_1p_2\dots p_n\geq 2*3*5*7*p_{n-2}p_{n-1}p_n>210*\frac{p_{n+1}}{2}\frac{p_{n+1}}{4}\frac{p_{n+1}}{8}=\frac{210p_{n+1}^3}{64}>p_{n+1}^3.$$
Cases $n=5,6$ can be easily checked manually.

Comment: we checked once, if you put   @lulu inside an answer, she does not get a notification flag. If you just want to acknowledge her contribution to everyone else, this is fine.